# pyinstaller hidden import tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.experimental when packing flask web application. Hook is unable to find from site-package

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyinstaller, hook, python-standalone

Trying to distribute a program that relies on tensorflow...
I am using pyinstaller to convert the flask web app to standalone exe file using following command
tensorflow==2.5.0 and
Python 3.9.4 cannot pack tensorflow hidden packages
How to resolve this issue?

`pyinstaller run.spec`

run.spec file code given below

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

block_cipher = None


hiddenimports = collect_submodules('tensorflow')
print(hiddenimports)

datas = collect_data_files('tensorflow', subdir=None, include_py_files=True)

hiddenimports.append('tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.callbacks')

added_files = [('templates', 'templates'), ('static', 'static'),('MOA.db','.'),('requirements.txt','.')]
#added_files.append(("jre8/win","jre8/win"))
added_files.extend(datas)

a = Analysis(['run.py'],
             pathex=['.','MOA_integration/Models'],
             binaries=[],
             datas= added_files,
             hiddenimports = hiddenimports,
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='run',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

terminal errors given below

```
1067 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.5.1
1067 INFO: Python: 3.9.4 (conda)
1068 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
1442 INFO: UPX is not available.
2021-09-16 16:09:37.764723: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerro
r: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-09-16 16:09:37.765199: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your
machine.
8346 INFO: checking Analysis
8503 INFO: Building because hiddenimports changed
8503 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
8508 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
8533 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
11626 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\rahul\\anaconda3\\envs\\my-rdkit-env\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\ho
oks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
11629 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\rahul\\anaconda3\\envs\\my-rdkit-env\\lib'
15032 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
15312 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
15330 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\rahul\anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\python.exe
15408 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\rahul\anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\python39.dll
15633 INFO: Analyzing run.py
20888 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook setuptools.extern.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\rahul\\anaconda3\\envs\\my-rdkit-env\\lib\\site-packa
ges\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'.
21455 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\rahul\\anaconda3\\envs\\my-rdkit-env\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\
pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
21456 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\rahul\\anaconda3\\envs\\my-rdkit-env\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
28640 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\rahul\\anaconda3\\envs\\my-rdkit-env\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\
hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
68916 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\rahul\\anaconda3\\envs\\my-rdkit-env\\lib\\site-packag
es\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
123659 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.tools.compatibility.ipynb'
123663 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.experimental'
123664 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.experimental' not found
123664 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.autograph.core.converter_testing'
123669 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing'
123669 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing' not found
123670 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.utils.experimental'
123670 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.utils.experimental' not found
123670 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist'
123670 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist' not found
123671 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.data.kernel_tests.checkpoint_test_base'
123733 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.imagenet_utils'
123733 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.imagenet_utils' not found
123733 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2'
123734 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2' not found
123734 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.mixed_precision.experimental'
123734 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.mixed_precision.experimental' not found
123734 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing'
123735 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing' not found
123735 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet_v2'
123735 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet_v2' not found
123735 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing.text'
123736 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing.text' not found
123736 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.estimator.export.export_output'
123837 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.estimator.canned.metric_keys'
123887 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications'
123888 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications' not found
123888 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.debug.cli.offline_analyzer'
123891 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.keras.benchmarks'
123940 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.densenet'
123941 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.densenet' not found
123941 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.imdb'
123942 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.imdb' not found
123942 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.distribute.step_fn'
123945 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras'
123946 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras' not found
123946 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.util._pywrap_transform_graph'
123946 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_config'
123948 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_test_lib'
123978 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.training.distribution_strategy_context'
123980 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.core.example.example_parser_configuration_pb2'
123988 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2'
123989 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2' not found
123989 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications'
123989 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications' not found
123990 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.optimizers.schedules'
123990 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.optimizers.schedules' not found
123990 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.resnet'
123991 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.resnet' not found
123991 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.keras.api._v1.keras.callbacks.experimental'
124042 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras'
124043 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras' not found
124043 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.v1'
124043 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.v1' not found
124043 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.layers.experimental'
124044 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.layers.experimental' not found
124044 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.regularizers'
124044 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.regularizers' not found
124044 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.training.distribute'
124046 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.losses'
124047 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.losses' not found
124047 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.autograph.pyct.static_analysis.type_inference'
124063 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.framework.subscribe'
124071 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.keras.tests.model_subclassing_test_util'
124151 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.tpu.profiler.profiler_analysis_pb2_grpc'
124289 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.util.future_api'
124290 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.util.serialization'
124293 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications'
124294 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications' not found
124294 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.kernel_tests.cudnn_deterministic_base'
124348 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.estimator'
124349 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.estimator' not found
124349 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.constraints'
124349 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.constraints' not found
124349 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.estimator'
124350 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.estimator' not found
124350 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2'
124350 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2' not found
124350 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.vgg16'
124351 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.vgg16' not found
124351 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.constraints'
124351 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.constraints' not found
124351 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.layers'
124352 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.layers' not found
124352 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.imagenet_utils'
124352 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.imagenet_utils' not found
124352 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.kernelized_utils'
124355 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.boston_housing'
124356 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.boston_housing' not found
124356 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing.benchmarks'
124405 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.estimator.exporter'
124408 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.ops.initializers_ns'
124410 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.preprocessing.text'
124411 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.preprocessing.text' not found
124411 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.autograph.pyct.testing'
124461 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.ops.distributions.identity_bijector'
124484 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.kernel_tests.bias_op_base'
124498 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.callbacks.experimental'
124499 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.callbacks.experimental' not found
124499 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.inception_v3'
124500 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.inception_v3' not found
124500 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph'
124514 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.lite.tools'
124564 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.xception'
124565 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.xception' not found
124565 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.estimator.canned.dnn_linear_combined'
124568 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.tpu.tpu_estimator'
124571 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications'
124571 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications' not found
124571 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.optimizers'
124572 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.optimizers' not found
124572 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.estimator.canned.dnn'
124574 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.preprocessing.image'
124574 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.preprocessing.image' not found
124574 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.preprocessing.sequence'
124574 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.preprocessing.sequence' not found
124575 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.util.keyword_args'
124577 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.estimator.estimator_lib'
124589 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.platform.status_bar'
124592 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs.pandas_io'
124646 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.mixed_precision'
124646 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.mixed_precision' not found
124646 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.backend'
124647 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.backend' not found
124647 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision.test_util'
124653 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.backend'
124653 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.backend' not found
124654 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.imagenet_utils'
124654 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.imagenet_utils' not found
124654 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.preprocessing.text'
124655 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.preprocessing.text' not found
124655 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2'
124655 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2' not found
124655 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.callbacks'
124655 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.callbacks' not found
124656 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.keras.distribute.distribute_strategy_test'
124858 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.data.kernel_tests.test_base'
124869 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python._python_memory_checker_helper'
124870 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.eager.benchmarks_test_base'
124873 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.core.protobuf.bfc_memory_map_pb2'
124881 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.tools.compatibility.ast_edits'
125141 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.estimator.canned.boosted_trees_utils'
125144 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.optimization'
125148 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn'
125148 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn' not found
125148 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.tpu.client.version'
125150 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.premade'
125150 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.premade' not found
125150 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.datasets.reuters'
125151 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.datasets.reuters' not found
125151 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.matching_files'
125154 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.tools.api'
125204 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.backend'
125204 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.backend' not found
125205 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.kernel_tests.random.util'
125259 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.ops.linalg.linear_operator_test_util'
125288 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.activations'
125289 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.activations' not found
125289 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.tpu.error_handling'
125291 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.resnet'
125291 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.resnet' not found
125291 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.distribute.cluster_resolver.sagemaker_cluster_resolver'
125297 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.grappler.item'
125301 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.ops.structured.structured_tensor'
125386 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.initializers'
125387 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.initializers' not found
125387 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.vgg19'
125387 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.vgg19' not found
125388 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras'
125388 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras' not found
125388 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.experimental'
125388 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.experimental' not found
125388 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.callbacks'
125389 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.callbacks' not found
125389 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.premade'
125389 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.premade' not found
125389 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing.image'
125390 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing.image' not found
125390 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn'
125390 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn' not found
125390 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.boston_housing'
125391 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.boston_housing' not found
125391 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn'
125391 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn' not found
125391 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.mnist'
125391 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.mnist' not found
125391 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.vgg16'
125392 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.vgg16' not found
125392 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.distribute.single_loss_example'
125397 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.utils.experimental'
125397 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.utils.experimental' not found
125397 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.layers'
125398 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.layers' not found
125398 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs.queues.feeding_functions'
125451 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.resnet_v2'
125451 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.resnet_v2' not found
125451 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.testing'
125455 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.regularizers'
125456 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.regularizers' not found
125456 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.datasets.reuters'
125456 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.datasets.reuters' not found
125456 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.estimator.export'
125457 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.estimator.export' not found
125457 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.tools.compatibility.tf_upgrade_v2_safety'
125462 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.estimator.canned.parsing_utils'
125464 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.cifar100'
125464 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.cifar100' not found
125464 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.estimator.export'
125465 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.estimator.export' not found
125465 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs.numpy_io'
125467 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.platform.control_imports'
125469 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.nasnet'
125470 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.nasnet' not found
125470 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.framework.test_ops'
125764 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.losses'
125764 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.losses' not found
125765 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.debug.lib.debug_events_reader'
125800 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.mobilenet_v3'
125801 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.mobilenet_v3' not found
125801 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.ops.distributions.transformed_distribution'
125816 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.reuters'
125817 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.reuters' not found
125817 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing.preprocessing_test_utils'
125823 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn'
125824 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn' not found
125824 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.wrappers'
125824 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.wrappers' not found
125824 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet50'
125825 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet50' not found
125825 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing.sequence'
125825 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing.sequence' not found
125825 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.layers'
125826 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.layers' not found
125826 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.tpu.datasets'
125832 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.autograph.utils.testing'
125838 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.losses'
125839 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.losses' not found
125839 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet50'
125839 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet50' not found
125839 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.cifar10'
125840 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.cifar10' not found
125840 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow.python.util.example_parser_configuration'
125845 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.models'
125846 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.models' not found
125846 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet'
125846 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet' not found
```